# Colocar uma função dentro de um input

Tags: php

Olá queria saber como coloco uma função de "senhas" aleatórias dentro do input, o código de gerar senha aleatórias é este:

```
function geraSenha($tamanho = 8, $maiusculas = true, $numeros = true, $simbolos = false)
{
    $lmin = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
    $lmai = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
    $num = '1234567890';
    $simb = '!@#$%*-';
    $retorno = '';
    $caracteres = '';
    $caracteres .= $lmin;
    if ($maiusculas) $caracteres .= $lmai;
        if ($numeros) $caracteres .= $num;
            if ($simbolos) $caracteres .= $simb;
                $len = strlen($caracteres);
                for ($n = 1; $n <= $tamanho; $n++) {
                    $rand = mt_rand(1, $len);
                    $retorno .= $caracteres[$rand-1];
                }
    return $retorno;
}
?>
```

O código do Input é este

```
<input name='AwardID' id='AwardID' type='text' value="Senha aleatoria" maxlength='40' value='' />
```

E como bloqueia o input para não poder escrever? Agradeço a quem puder me ajudar desde já.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<input name='AwardID' id='AwardID' type='text' value="Senha aleatoria" maxlength='40' value='<?php echo geraSenha(8, true, true, false); ?>' readonly />
```

basta escrever o retorno da função dentro da propriedade **Value** e para não permitir alterar o texto adicione a tag **readonly**

Comment: Não carrega essa parte quando fiz isto fica assim: http://prntscr.com/diglvl

Comment: Perdão, tire a palavra function depois de echo

Comment: Obrigado amigo me ajudo muito, uma pergunta, tem como criar um botão que quando aperta gera outra senha e assim por diante?